# Horizontal Printing in Jasper Reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I was trying to print my reports horizontally with 3 columns. But it looks like even the column labels are repeated. It should repeat only where there is a overflow.

I am getting something like this:

[image: bad report]

The below image is what is expected.

[image: I want to get something like this]

Can anyone give me some hints.

Sam

Comment: can you please post an image of what you are actually getting?

Comment: i added the image - at the moment the column name is repeating which is also causing space issue.